# Constructor with multiple possible Classes

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement a constructor that can access class objects of two or more possible.
(PS. This is an inner class, for those who question the static class)

```
...

public static class Builder {
    protected String mTitle;
    protected List<ReviewItem> mPages = new ArrayList<ReviewItem>();
    protected boolean mRequired = false;
    protected String mParentKey;
    private final ModelCallbacks mModelCallbacks;
    private final Class<Fragment> mFragmentClass;

    public Builder(String title, ModelCallbacks callbacks, Class<PageFragment> clazz) {
        mTitle = title;
        mModelCallbacks = callbacks;
        mFragmentClass = clazz;
    }

    public Builder(String title, ModelCallbacks callbacks, Class<ListPageFragment> clazz) {
        mTitle = title;
        mModelCallbacks = callbacks;
        mFragmentClass = clazz;
    }

}

...
```

ListPageFragment inheritance

```
java.lang.Object    
    ↳    android.app.Fragment
        ↳    android.app.ListFragment
            ↳    my.app.ListPageFragment
```

PageFragment inheritance

```
java.lang.Object    
    ↳    android.app.Fragment
        ↳    my.app.PageFragment
```

Error:

> Method Builder(String, ModelCallbacks, Class) has the
>   same erasure Builder(String, ModelCallbacks, Class) as another
>   method in type Page.Builder

The current error makes sense, but how can I implement or ensure that `clazz` is of type PageFragment or ListPageFragment?

Comment: `public static class Builder` in java you can't define a class static , only if is an inner class

Comment: It is an inner class but it's not related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the signature as follows -

```
public Builder(String title, ModelCallbacks callbacks, Class<? extends Fragment> clazz) {
```

That way you won't need two or more constructors, one will be enough.

And you can change the field declaration -

```
private final Class<? extends Fragment> mFragmentClass;
```

---

The compilation error is because all the generic type information are erased (which means to replace all the parameterised types with their raw version e.g. `Class<ListPageFragment>` with just `Class`) after compilation. In your case, following is what the signature of both the constructors would after type erasing -

```
public Builder(String title, ModelCallbacks callbacks, Class clazz) {
```

---

**Edit**

If you have to limit the possible types to the two you mentioned then you it be better to have two static-factory-methods instead -

```
public static Builder withPageFragment(String title, 
                                       ModelCallbacks callbacks, 
                                       Class<PageFragment> clazz) {
     //...
}

public static Builder withListPageFragment(String title, 
                                           ModelCallbacks callbacks, 
                                           Class<ListPageFragment> clazz) {
     //...
}
```

Comment: in android can you define a static class?

Comment: All of this is just regular Java language feature (Android is no special case). I am not what you exactly mean by static class. Can you explain?

Comment: `public static class Builder` in java you can't define a class static , only if is an inner class

Comment: Yes that is correct, only nested class can be static (if they appear within some class). Classes can have members, if any of the members is made static that means that the member would belong to the class itself.

Comment: @BheshGurung and if I wanted to ensure it was only either `PageFragment` or `ListPageFragment` which methods of Class would be the best to use? `isAssignableFrom`, `isInstance`, etc. That's really part of the question.

Comment: Actually, `Class<? extends Fragment>` is really not a good idea, if you need to limit the possible types to those two. IMO, the best way to handle this would be to use two different static-factory-methods (one for each type). e.g. one could be `public static Builder withPageFragment(String title, ModelCallbacks callbacks, Class<PageFragment> clazz) {`. That way signature won't clash, because with methods you can have different names.

Comment: Was hoping for the possibilities of something better but I guess that's just how it is. Thank you, i'll accept your answer as it gives yet another (improved) alternative.